# mutual information equivalence

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus, information-theory

So I am looking to show:

$$I(X;Y|Z) = I(Y;Z|X) − I(Y;Z) + I(X;Y)$$

I started with rewriting it with the sum

$$\sum_{x,y,z} p_{XYZ}\log_2\frac{p_{XY}(x,y|z)}{p_X(x|z)p_Y(y|z)}$$

But I do not really know where to go from there.

Do i need to split it up?

Cheers,
Avocari

Comment: Hint: This is natural from the [chain rule for mutual information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information#Chain_rule_for_mutual_information). Try to prove the same.

Comment: You don't need to write the sum, just use the property $I(X;Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y)$